# Trying out scrolldeck example

Tags: javascript

I just came across scrolldeck js and was trying to test it but it seems I am missing something in the doc. For me documentation doesn't look that helpful. May be its just me.

Can someone please have a look and check whats wrong in my implementation?

Problem is that scrolldeck is not "scrolling". It is working like a simple anchor jump.

Link for the Gist of my HTML file is : https://gist.github.com/keshavagrawal89/a2c875c88278d2a6c663

Thanks

Comment: I know there are no style sheets but thats what I am wondering. Is that required?

Comment: Nevermind I found another js which suits my requirement of scrolling. Thanks. Will explore this one sometime later.